# play scala tuple form with multiple case class mapping in views

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have a form in controller Authentication.scala:

```
      package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

import models.User
import models.UserProfile


/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class Authentication @Inject() extends Controller {

  val registerForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "user" -> mapping(
        "email" -> nonEmptyText,
        "password" -> nonEmptyText
        )(User.apply)(User.unapply),
      "profile" -> mapping(
        "firstname"->nonEmptyText,
        "lastname"->nonEmptyText,
        "gender" -> ignored(0)
      )(UserProfile.apply)(UserProfile.unapply))
    )

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page with a welcome message.
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def login = Action {
    Ok(views.html.login())
  }

  def loginSubmit = Action {
    implicit request => 
    // val maybeFoo = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("password").lift(0) // returns an Option[String]
    // val something = maybeFoo map {_.toString} getOrElse 0
    // println(something)
    Ok("Hello")
  }

  def register = Action{
    Ok(views.html.register())
  }

  def registerSubmit = Action{
    implicit request =>
    registerForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        // binding failure, you retrieve the form containing errors:
        println(formWithErrors)
        BadRequest(views.html.register())
      },
      userData => {
        /* binding success, you get the actual value. */
        Redirect(routes.Authentication.register())
      }
    )
  }

  def forgotPassword = Action{
    Ok(views.html.forgot_password())
  }

}
```

And I have a view register.scala.html:

```
    @import b3.vertical.fieldConstructor
@(userForm: Form[tuple(Mapping, Mapping)])(implicit messages: Messages)
@main("Register") {
    <!-- REGISTRATION FORM -->
<div class="text-center" style="padding:50px 0">
    <div class="logo">register</div>
    <!-- Main Form -->
    <div class="login-form-1">
        <form id="register-form" class="text-left" method="POST" action="@routes.Authentication.registerSubmit">
            <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
            <div class="main-login-form">
                <div class="login-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reg_email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reg_email" name="email" placeholder="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reg_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password_confirm" class="sr-only">Password Confirm</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirm" name="reg_password_confirm" placeholder="confirm password">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstname" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group login-group-checkbox">
                        <input type="radio" class="" name="gender" id="male" placeholder="username">
                        <label for="male">male</label>

                        <input type="radio" class="" name="gender" id="female" placeholder="username">
                        <label for="female">female</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group login-group-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="reg_agree" name="reg_agree">
                        <label for="reg_agree">i agree with <a href="#">terms</a></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="login-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="etc-login-form">
                <p>already have an account? <a href="#">login here</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end:Main Form -->
</div>
}
```

- I know that I am not sending the form in the parameter for view.html.register(), but the question is how to implement the import in the views, with such a form like that? I am getting error all the time.

Help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Should the type of your form in the template parameter not be `Form[(User, UserProfile)]`?

Comment: @Mikesname thats what I did already, and that works. Thanks for the reply anyways. Put your suggestion as answer, and I will tag it as accepted answer, I could answer mine too as I figures it out but, I am glad that someone replied, so I will honor your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a form using `tuple(mapping(...), mapping(...))` the *type* of the form is a tuple of the mapping's types. So in this case you want the type of the view's form parameter to be `Form[(User, UserProfile)]`.

```
@(userForm: Form[(User, UserProfile)])(implicit messages: Messages)

@main("Register") {
    ... HTML ...
}
```